# How can I search a string in a pdf file, and find the physical page number of each page where the string appears?

Tags: pdf, search

Given a PDF file, I would like to search for a string in its text, and I know `pdfgrep` can do that.

I further would like to have the physical page number of each page where the string appears  (as opposed to the page number printed on each page).

Is there some program that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `pdfgrep` can do that, with the `-n` option. All you need to do is add that before your search string.

Comment: Thanks. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457844/how-can-i-get-the-page-numbers-only-of-a-pattern-in-a-pdf-file-regardless-if-th